# Alarm manager with asynctask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alarmmanager

i have a application where i have to send gps(location) updates every 10 minutes to a server.So i am using alarm manager.I have read that async task is the best way for communicating with a server.is there any other way for sending the location updates?or is this a good method?

Comment: You can use `Asynctask` or simply use a `Thread`

Comment: @AndroidWarrior will the asynctask work for low end device also?Or the OS will kill it?

Comment: Use a `BroadcastReceiver` with an `IntentService`

Comment: `AsynTask` will work just fine it was added in `API lvl 3`